# Java substring is switching my positive indexes with negative ones

Tags: java, html, string, swing, jtextpane

I have come to the conclusion HTML enabled JTextPanes do not support word wrapping.  So I am attempting to provide a home brew method.  I will post it on the 'net once it is complete.  I may not have the greatest technique but it should work when it's done.  My problem is for some insane (very fustrating) reason when I pass an index to my substring command it switches the actual value with the same value but in negitive and throws a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.  But when the variable is sent to the substring command it is positive for sure.  When I substitute the variables for values it works fine.  I would appreciate any help.  I will include the soure.

```
    String wordWrap( String oldtxt )    {

        int ishere = 0;         // the current index
        int charlen = 0;        // The current length of the current line
        int beginint = 0;       // Where the text between tags begins
        int endint = 0;         // Where the text between tags ends
        String tempstr = "";    // Where the text is 
        String newoldtxt = "";  // to work around the damned oc error
        String newtxt = "";     // The new text being built
        String divystr = "";    // Temp variable to hold a partial string
        Boolean a = true;       // Needed as temp storage variable

        newoldtxt = oldtxt;

        while( true ) {

            endint = oldtxt.indexOf( "<", endint );

            if( endint == -1 )  {

                endint = oldtxt.length();
                a = false;
            }


            ishere = endint;
            tempstr = oldtxt.substring( beginint, endint );             // Save the text in a temp string

            while( ishere > endint )
            if( tempstr.length() > ( 22 - charlen ))  {                 // Testing for a complete line

//              newtxt += tempstr.substring( ishere, 22 - charlen );        // If a line is complete a line is printed to the pane
                newtxt += tempstr.substring( ishere, 22 );      // If a line is complete a line is printed to the pane
                ishere += 22 - charlen;                                     // Bumping the current index along
                charlen = 0;
                newtxt += "<br />";                                         // Attach a line break
                if( ishere >= tempstr.length() && a == false )
                return newtxt;

            } else if( tempstr.length() < ( 22 - charlen) )  {          // Checking to see if there are fewer then 22 chars in the string

                divystr = tempstr.substring( ishere, tempstr.length() );    // Dump the rest of the substring into the rebuilt string
                newtxt += divystr;                                          // Assign the remaining tempstr characters to newtxt
                charlen += divystr.length();                                // Add stray chars to charlen

                if( a == false )
                    return newtxt;
            }

            beginint = oldtxt.indexOf( ">", ( endint ) );                       // Locate end bracke
            newtxt += oldtxt.substring( beginint, endint );             // Add tag to newtxt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Roland Sams wrote `do not support word wrapping` I think that that's isn't true at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the final `substring` call, the value of `endint` is 0, which is larger than the start index, resulting in a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
// endint is larger than beginint here
newtxt += oldtxt.substring( beginint, endint );
```

Comment: Yeh, thanks but I tried that already. I still get the out of bounds error.  This code is not release code yet.  I haven't got a chance to chase out the bugs yet because of this nasty glitch

Comment: What do you use as input data? The value of `endint` is determined by the location of the first `<` sign in `oldtxt`.

Comment: BTW: The out of bounds exception was -21 the actual index should have been 21.  I am certian the variable sent as the index was 21 for some reason the substring method reversed it.

Comment: The `substring` didn't reverse them, try printing both the start and end index right before the call to `substring`. You'll notice that the end index is less than the start index.

Comment: endint was to detect the opening bracket for an HTML tag so the method could process it properly

Comment: The problem I am having is just before (I used message boxes to track it down) the variable is sent to my substring it is (for sure) 21 when the substring method processes it, it becomes -21 and throws the exception

Comment: I also tried patching it with ones complement but that didn't work either?  I am really at wits end over this :(

Comment: Regardless of which `substring` call it happens for, the problem is the same. Check the value of both parameters you pass to it.

Comment: I may be making some progress.  I switched the variables and it seems to be accepting them

Comment: ok for some odd world reason I can use new variables but the original ones don't work unless I assign them to newly created variables. Ok seems to be solved.  Thanks much for your responce fivedigit